# How to add .html extensions in drupal project

Tags: drupal, file-extension

html extensions in drupal nodes. like i have project

```
abc.com/node/1
abc.com/node/2
abc.com/node/3
```

now i want to add

```
abc.com/node/1.html
```

or

```
abc.com/node/1.php
```

etc

i heard from some one that there is module available for this if it is then please tell me that module name and also if via changing files or template files also tell me how can i do that

Thanks

Comment: i got this... install Path Auto module and URL Alias from admin menu site building > url alias -> Automated alias settings -> Node paths ->

content/[title-raw]

change this to 

content/[title-raw].html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on a node-by-node basis, you can use Drupal's core Path module.  When it is enabled and you are creating a node, you should see a fieldset titled `URL path settings`.  Insert your custom path alias there, save the node and then you can access the node from that path.

If you want to assign path aliases by a type of content (ex. for all polls have an alias of `example.com/poll/#`) you can use the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto).  This is extremely useful for generating URL aliases.  Even if you have a pattern in place for a type of content, you can always override it using the `URL path settings` fieldset.

You can change create URL alias patterns at `admin/build/path/pathauto`.  For help with the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), see the [Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/pathauto).